# IRR excel function with dynamic non contiguous cells

Tags: dynamic, irr

I am trying to calculate the IRR where the cells are not adjacent - Please see below. I have attempted to use Offset function and have had no success. Is there a way to calculate IRR for the below format?

```
        NSW  |  VIC  | 2018        NSW  |  VIC  | 2019       NSW  |  VIC  | 2020   
Capex  ($10k)  ($5k)   ($15k) etc...
CF                                 $5k     $3k      $8k   etc..
```

Where NSW & VIC rolls up to the year.
I want to calculate the IRR at an annual level - how do I do that if the years are not next to each other and the number of years will dynamically change?

Thanks in Advance!